# MPNowPlayingInfoCenter AVPlayer on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, avplayer, avqueueplayer, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I'm making an app that streams music. I'm trying to display metadata (title, artist and artwork image) on the lock screen.

`MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` seems to work well with `MediaPlayer.framework`, but I can't figure to make it work with `AVPlayer` on iOS 7.

**The player is working well in background mode** thanks to `AVAudioSession` :

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];    
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
[session setActive:YES error:&error];
```

Here is my code for displaying metadata on lockscreen (**which doesn't work**) :

```
Class playingInfoCenter = NSClassFromString(@"MPNowPlayingInfoCenter");

if (playingInfoCenter)
{
    NSDictionary *nowPlaying = @{MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: currentTrack.artist,
                                 MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle: currentTrack.title};

    [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:nowPlaying];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks for reading this :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found the answer of my question !

When using background audio, you must specify that your app can received remote control Events :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

Comment: When I start playing a song. I call this method too, when I'm not playing anymore : [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

Comment: thanks for your reply. actually still no luck, I use the https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer , to stream the radio. I wanna show the radio station picture on the lock screen, every data are there. just not show on lock screen :(

Comment: what i mean is every data is there meaning I got all the information that i need and fill it in dictionary .. but on lock screen has no control there , no album title, no image there . and i do put this, but this no luck   
    [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:nowPlaying];

Comment: Did you check "Audio and Airplay", under "background modes" ? it's in your project settings under "capabilities".

Comment: you mean in infoplist? "Required background modes" i have set it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49462/discussion-between-remy-virin-and-justicepenny)

Comment: Hello @RémyVirin have you been able to solve your issue... i am also struck on same issue can you pls help me?

Comment: @Rohit, yes but how ?Have you tried what I suggest ?

Comment: @RémyVirin i have tried it and magically i got it working for iOS 8 that too for downloaded files not for files streaming from server. I could not understand where i am going wrong have search many other answers also but could only got it working for iOS 8 (downloaded files only). Thanks for help..

Comment: This answer helped me. Works for streaming video / HLS live video.